# Using variable_get from DrupalWebTestCase

Tags: 7, testing, configuration

I would like to pull certain configuration items from settings.php from a DrupalWebTestCase in order to test my module (in this case, a SFTP module).
I want to do it this way so that I don't hardcode my SFTP credentials.

For example, in my DrupalWebTestCase, I have:

```
  public function test_sftp()
  {
    $this->assertTrue(variable_get('mymodule_test_sftp'));
    // then I would try to connect, etc....
  }
```

In settings.php:

```
$conf['mymodule_test_sftp'] = array(
 'host' => 'example.com',
 // etc...
);
```

When I run the unit testing suite, this unit test fails, the value returned by variable_get is NULL.

**Edit:**

Running the code below, returns the correct database settings, but I get "**Undefined index: mymodule_test_sftp**":

```
  public function test_sftp()
  {
    global $databases, $conf;
    $this->assertTrue($databases);
    $this->assertTrue($conf['mymodule_test_sftp']);
  }
```

Comment: Have you used variables_set('mymodule_test_sftp', $variable); first?

Comment: No, but I do not want to hard code my credentials. That's why I want to use settings.php

Comment: in your simpletest check the db values manually to ensure they are there

Comment: See my edit, it does pull the right databases information. I also tried with global $conf, but this still gives an error.

Comment: Simpletest is running on separate Drupal instance witch don't have setting.php edited by you. variable_get() gets you values from system.variable but in your simpletest from simpletestxxxx.system.variable I suposse

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this is helpful! So if I understand correctly there's no good way to achieve this?

Comment: Except you struggle arround to design your test to edit used settings.php like normally admin (you) would do:)

Comment: Do you have an example that would work? Maybe submit it as an answer?

Comment: Unlucky no idea, but anyway I wouldnt test it like this. The Whole application will depend on this credential so if they are not there. you cant do much about it. if the credentials are stored in db anyway, why don't you make config page for your module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just faced a similar issue. What I have found out is that in your `DrupalWebTestCase` child class you still have access to all variables defined in `settings.php` before calling `parent::setUp()`. Which means you can do something like this:

```
class MymoduleWebTestCase extends DrupalWebTestCase {

  public function setUp() {
    $mymodule_test_sftp = variable_get('mymodule_test_sftp');

    parent::setUp();

    variable_set('mymodule_test_sftp', $mymodule_test_sftp);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the current Drupal 7, I found that the above is only true the first time the test case setUp() method is called. On subsequent calls, the values from settings.php will either be gone or replaced by what was in the database, which is not always the same. A local development instance of a site, for example, might have a definition for "site_name" that is different from the "site_name" value in the database copied from the live site.

You can catch that first value and use it thereafter:

```
class MymoduleWebTestCase extends DrupalWebTestCase {

  public function setUp() {
    static $mymodule_test_sftp = NULL;
    if ($mymodule_test_sftp === NULL) {
        // if it's not defined, don't keep checking
        $mymodule_test_sftp = variable_get('mymodule_test_sftp', FALSE);
    }

    parent::setUp();

    if ($mymodule_test_sftp) {
        variable_set('mymodule_test_sftp', $mymodule_test_sftp);
    }
  }
 
}
```